# Codeigniter rest controller post response as xml format

Tags: php, json, xml, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter REST_Controller for making API calls,
when I tried to get call with format( json / xml / HTML ), and its working

but when I tried to make the post call, here I need XML data as a result but it always failed to get XML data. It's always showing JSON data only. Here am sharing a screenshot of my problem

[image]

My Controller is

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class User extends REST_Controller {

    public function index_post()
    {
        $this->response($this->post());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass format=xml in screenshot it shows html

Comment: Check [docs](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#content-types). Your URL should looks like `http://localhost/resume/user?format=xml`.

Comment: Yeah! I have tried it too,It's not working

Comment: I need a solution for a POST request, can I send data like this 'http://localhost/resume/user?format=xml', even though it's not working

Answer (score 0):

REST_Controlleris using server variable CONTENT_TYPE to detect format type using below method in library:

```
protected function _detect_input_format()
    {
        // Get the CONTENT-TYPE value from the SERVER variable
        $content_type = $this->input->server('CONTENT_TYPE');
        if (empty($content_type) === FALSE)
        {
            // If a semi-colon exists in the string, then explode by ; and get the value of where
            // the current array pointer resides. This will generally be the first element of the array
            $content_type = (strpos($content_type, ';') !== FALSE ? current(explode(';', $content_type)) : $content_type);
            // Check all formats against the CONTENT-TYPE header
            foreach ($this->_supported_formats as $type => $mime)
            {
                // $type = format e.g. csv
                // $mime = mime type e.g. application/csv
                // If both the mime types match, then return the format
                if ($content_type === $mime)
                {
                    return $type;
                }
            }
        }
```

You can write your own method in case of POST Request and use.